# Free Online Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

Can anybody recommend a good free online Team Foundation Server repository?

I found [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/) but it's only for open source projects.

Comment: Microsoft lists several TFS hosting partners on its website: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-foundation-server/hosting. As far as I know, there is no free service. TFS Service Preview is free now because it's still beta, but it will cost money once it is "official".

Answer (score 71):

Upto five team members it is free. Try it :)

http://tfs.visualstudio.com/

Comment: the free plan only works with [visual studio 2012](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/pricing/information/)

Comment: No, in addition to VS 2012 [you can also use](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/code/connect-vs/) Visual Studio 2010 with Service Pack 1 and KB2662296, or Visual Studio 2008 SP1 with 'GDR update'. If you use their Git support, you can [ANY Git client](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/home/news/2013/jan-30/).

Comment: I wrote on how to make it work with both Visual Studio versions [HERE](http://solvedcode.blogspot.com/2013/02/solved-how-to-connect-to-microsofts.html). Hope someone finds it useful.

Comment: I use VS 2013 and the plan still works.

Comment: Well I am using in VS 2013 ultimate edition with 3 other developers it is working fine and off course it is free :)

Comment: New link  https://www.visualstudio.com/tfs/

Comment: I'm using with VS2017 community edition, created project and added 5 users, works perfectly fine free

Comment: A little bit late comment: I had a code uploaded to tfs.visualstudio.com, a few years ago, but now I see that this web site is unreachable. Could I find this code somewhere, is it moved somewhere automatically or it is lost forever?

Answer (score 18):

Free is TFS hosted on Windows Azure: http://tfspreview.com/

If you need more info about TFSPreview, please read Brian Harry's MSDN blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/09/14/team-foundation-server-on-windows-azure.aspx

To obtain activation code just register there or contact someone from MS ALM team.

**Update:** *TFS Preview* goes live&stable as **Visual Studio Online** here: http://www.visualstudio.com still free for 5 team members and build server computing time. Another nice feature automatic build&deploy (daily or continuous integration) to Azure. More info: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/

Comment: TFS preview is supposed to be coming out of 'Preview' mode today and available to try for free. This was announced by Scott Guthrie at TechEd 2012.

Comment: Still in preview and no prices available http://tfspreview.com/en-us/pricing/information/

Comment: @JPHellemons visit tfs.visualstudio.com it's now free for upto 5 team members

Comment: @Saeedouv I already have an account :) I had TFS in a LAN, but this is much better because of less server maintenance for me and no firewall, port opening router issues :) Really like it! http://tfs.visualstudio.com

Answer (score 8):

Readify used to run their TFSNow hosted TFS service, but I don't think it's going any longer.  The only others I've heard of, apart from CodePlex, aren't free:

- [Phase2](http://www.phase2.com/hosted_team_foundation_server_overview2.aspx)
- [TeamDevCentral](http://www.teamdevcentral.com/overview.html)
- [Saas Made Easy](http://www.saasmadeeasy.com/tf_server.html)

Answer (score 8):

I know this thread is old, but since a Google search brought me here, it will also do to other people who may find this useful.

Microsoft recenly launched **Visual Studio Online**, which is free for projects with up to 5 users:

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-online-overview-vs.aspx

I have been using it for a while, and it integrates completely with Visual Studio 2013. It claims integration with other IDEs too. Apart from TFS, Git can also be used with it.

I know this thread is old, but since a Google search brought me here

Answer (score 4):

VSO is now Azure DevOps https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vso

Recently Microsoft Visual Studio Online (VSO) is now Azure DevOps

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/vso/) for free. Also you can import a TFS repo to this cloud space.

Answer (score 2):

[tfs.visualstudio.com](http://tfs.visualstudio.com)

This is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

One of recent the [TFS Rocks](http://www.radiotfs.com/) pocasts mentioned such an organisation, may have been number 16.