# Create Project for Online Work TFS

Tags: tfs, repository

Is there any way to work on the same project online, (for free)?
Like Team Foundation Server online.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free Online Team Foundation Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625552/free-online-team-foundation-server)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're low on details, it's hard to answer with more than a couple of hints;

If you're a fan of TFS and are doing Open Source, [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/) should work right out of the box.

If you're not doing open source, [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) is pretty good, but it does not supply TFS, only [GIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)) and [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial).

These are only two, there are [many more](http://www.google.se/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=free+source+control+hosting).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft currently offers a preview of [Team Foundation Server hosted on Windows Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/09/14/team-foundation-server-on-windows-azure.aspx).  There is currently no charge for this service (although there will be a pricing model announced at some point.)

Otherwise, there are a number of Team Foundation Server hosting providers.  Microsoft [provides a list](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-foundation-server/hosting).  None of them are free.

As Joachim Isaksson mentioned, [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/) is a free service that provides Team Foundation Server hosting, but your code will be public.